# Python 3 Prints unintended escape characters when concatenating complex strings

Tags: string, bash, python-3.x, escaping, os.system

I am sending complex commands, messages, and what not to os.system for reasons.  I ran into a snag when sending URLs in quotes, in lieu of command structure that also used apostrophes.  I have tried format, raw, unicode, concat, writing it out, escaping, playing with using quotes or apostrophes on certain strings, and no matter what I do, python will add magic "\" escape strings inside of my new string, which is syntactically bad when using bash commands.

## string vars

```
com1 = 'command -X ARG '
url1 = '"https://big-long.webaddress.com/folder/151515-15151-515151blah?token=ABC123"'
com2 = " -H \"DATA-TYPE:app/data\" --flag '{\"Stuff\":\""
message = 'This is a test message'
com3 = "\"}'"
```

## ex1

```
newstr = com1 + url1 + com2 + message + com3
```

prints:

'command -X ARG "https://big-long.webaddress.com/folder/151515-15151-515151blah?token=ABC123" -H "DATA-TYPE:app/data" --flag \'{"Stuff":"This is a test message"}\''

## commentary

variables com2 and com3 escapes the apostrophes for some reason, but actually writes the "\" character.

## ex2

I can actually concat two nice strings and upon completion, get magic "\" escape characters printed out.

```
v1 = "'Stuff'"
v2 = '"Stuff"'

v1+v2
```

Prints: '\'Stuff\'"Stuff"'

Even escaping the ' in v1 yields the same result.

## The Question

What exactly is going on with the printing magic escape characters, and what do I need to do to properly mix and mash quotes and apostrophes?  I need to send commands to the system and finding documentation on the magic \ is leading me no where.  Thanks in advance.

## Additional

I am sending the string to os.system() because it is actually a curl script running in linux bash.

```
"command -X ARG %s -H \"DATA-TYPE:app/data\" --flag '{\"Stuff\":\"%s\"}'" % (url1,message)
```

also sends additional \ characters on the apostrophes...

Comment: How do you expect `v1+v2` to be represented? You will get what you want if you `print(v1+v2)`

Comment: @quamrana I was just giving an example of a phenomena I am not used to.  I don't have problems with strings in Java or C#.  That was just more of a, "hey, why does it do this?" example.

Comment: I found success creating a bash script on the linux side and sending a couple of strings to it.  I could not get python to accept a bunch of double and single quotes together.  It always writes additional \ characters.